# has anyone ever tried deploying a laravel project on app engine that uses mongodb as the database?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, google-app-engine, deployment

I am trying to deploy my Laravel 8 REST API to Google App Engine. It runs pretty fine on my local machine but when I try to deploy it to AppEngine, I get the error saying that "Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found". Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

extension=mongodb.so to the php.ini